# Adding Module Dependency on Android Studio

Tags: android, module, android-studio, dependencies

I'm making my own android project and I want to use 3rd party library for my project.I downloaded FoldableLayout from github.Link is below

https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout

and then I added library folder from FoldableLayout into my project with this order :`root project -> new -> Module -> Import Exiting Project ->FoldableLayout-master/library` as an module

After that,I added compile project(':library') into app/build.gradle

but I'm getting an error

```
Error:(13, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK' on com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated@f7fcd4e.
```

I added all Screen Shots are below

[image]
    app's Project Structure -> Dependencies

[image]

```
Root Project's setting.gradle file
```

[image]

```
app's build.gradle file
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the sample provided with FoldableLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself :)

The problem was in gradle.properties

I need to add these lines into my on MyProject/gradle.properties

```
VERSION_NAME=1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
VERSION_CODE=4
GROUP=com.alexvasilkov

POM_DESCRIPTION=Android widgets to implement folding animation
POM_URL=https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout
POM_SCM_URL=https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout
POM_SCM_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout.git
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout.git
POM_LICENCE_NAME=The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
POM_LICENCE_URL=http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo
POM_DEVELOPER_ID=alexvasilkov
POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Alex Vasilkov

ANDROID_MIN_SDK=14
ANDROID_TARGET_SDK=20
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK=20
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=20.0.0
```

Comment: And this is from the sample provided with FoldableLayout, right?